# Java Entry Validation

Tags: java

I'm working on a server/client battleship game using sockets. Part of the project requires entry validation on the client side for entering tile locations. A user is supposed to enter a letter A-E and a number 1-5, and right now if you type in something invalid, it seems to freeze. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
            do{
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"); 
            System.out.println("Please type in a board position in the format of a letter followed by number, such as 'A1'. "); 
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  
            String BoardChoice = sc.next();  
            if(BoardChoice.equals("A1" ) || BoardChoice.equals("B1" ) || BoardChoice.equals("C1" ) || BoardChoice.equals("D1" ) || BoardChoice.equals("E1" ) || 
               BoardChoice.equals("A2" ) || BoardChoice.equals("B2" ) || BoardChoice.equals("C2" ) || BoardChoice.equals("D2" ) || BoardChoice.equals("E2" ) || 
               BoardChoice.equals("A3" ) || BoardChoice.equals("B3" ) || BoardChoice.equals("C3" ) || BoardChoice.equals("D3" ) || BoardChoice.equals("E3" ) || 
               BoardChoice.equals("A4" ) || BoardChoice.equals("B4" ) || BoardChoice.equals("C4" ) || BoardChoice.equals("D4" ) || BoardChoice.equals("E4" ) || 
               BoardChoice.equals("A5" ) || BoardChoice.equals("B5" ) || BoardChoice.equals("C5" ) || BoardChoice.equals("D5" ) || BoardChoice.equals("E5" ))
            {
                flagtoo = false;
                writer.writeUTF(BoardChoice); 
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Input Please re-enter!");
            }
            }while(flagtoo);
```

Comment: not sure but maybe move `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); `  before the `do` statement

Comment: `String BoardChoice = sc.next();  ` should be `String BoardChoice = sc.nextLine();` otherwise you're never reading to the end of the buffer

Comment: Yep! turns out that's all it was. Thanks!

Comment: FYI: you could simply you validation by using something like `BoardChoice.matches("[A-E][1-5]")`, which will return `false` if the input is not valid

Comment: "That's all it was"... which one?  There are two suggestions in the comments.

Comment: The above code works for me as is, running on Windows in Command Prompt.  Perhaps reopening a new Scanner might fail on some platforms.  (It's not the right thing to do, though.)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you test each character separately by breaking them out with `charAt`, and *please* respect variable naming conventions. Something like

```
boolean valid = false;
String boardChoice = sc.nextLine(); // <-- not next
if (boardChoice.length() == 2) {
    char col = boardChoice.charAt(0);
    char row = boardChoice.charAt(1);
    // The parenthesis here are just for clarity.
    valid = ((col >= 'A' && col <= 'E') && (row >= '1' && row <= '5'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion on the other hand will suggest to implement regex with a pattern that allows you to match 1st char alpha(no matter capitalization) followed by a number,
both in a range from a → e and 1 → 5

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please type in a ....y number, such as 'A1'. ");

    do {
        inp = sc.nextLine();
        if (inp.matches("^[a-eA-E1-5]{0,2}")) {
            inpArr[k++] = inp;

        } else {
            System.out.println("invalid input");
        }
    } while (k < numberOfElements);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inpArr));
```